# How to create a pattern border around webpage, squarespace

Tags: website-design, css, website-templates

I'm trying to create a specific border around a squarespace page so that is responsive (i don't want to add an image as it wouldn't adapt to other devices) This is what I am hoping for:

[image: web frames]

I currently can only get a solid double border reaching the edges of the page with minimal spacing between the lines - about half of what I'm hoping for.

So far this is the code i've inserted into the custom css:

```
#footer {display:none;}
body {
border: 1em double #ffffff;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/LhxKJpU.jpg);
background-repeat: tile; 

}
```

The template i'm using is Pacific.

Any ideas??

Comment: Do you want the lines to be a fixed width? Or percentage? Is the cross pattern in every corner or just the bottom right?

Comment: Quick idea—overlap a different bordered shape on each corner. You could do it with pseudo-elements on the header and footer—or something like that. I'll do a test later.

Comment: Hi @Zach Saucier, i want them to be a fixed width and the cross pattern is for every corner. I'm not sure how to do pseudo-elements ...

Answer (score 1):

You cant do that Directly with CSS over the body tag directly, you have re-structure you html body to achieve the desire effect.

All you have to do is four different DIV's overlapped over each others and each DIV deal with a single border, DIV for have only one border on top position and the other have it on the right position and so one.

here is my solution:

```
<head>
<style>
body {
    margin:0px;
    background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/LhxKJpU.jpg);
    }
.top, .left, .right, .bottom {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    }   
.top {
    border-top: 1em double #fff; top: 40px; z-index:100;
    }
.left {
    border-left: 1em double #fff; left: 40px; z-index:200;
    }
.right {
    border-right: 1em double #fff; right: 40px; z-index:300;
    }
.bottom {
    border-bottom: 1em double #fff; bottom: 40px; z-index:400;
    }           
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="top"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="bottom"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my result

[image]

by the way there is no `tile` value for repeating a background. you have to choose between `repeat-x` `repeat-y` `no-repeat` and `repeat`

Comment: as far as im aware you cant edit the HTML on squarespace's premade templates (you can on your own templates).. you could do the same thing with pseudo-elements if you dont have access to the HTML

Comment: Actually.. You should probably do it with pseudo-elements anyway, unless those `div`s already exist and mean something.

Comment: @CAI Squarespace actually gives you quite a bit of control. I only once briefly scouted out if Squarespace was any good, so I can't remember exact details, but I believe you need to enable [Developer Platform](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545717) and then you can edit html and css. I liked the way Squarespace templates were pretty clean.

Comment: @Joonas I've never used it so I don't know but from what I read it sounded like you can only use the developer platform to create your own themes and not with their pre-made themes. I may be wrong though.

Comment: My point still stands that you shouldn't add unnecessary html markup anyway :)

Comment: @CAI The way I remember it, by default it gives you the active theme to be edited, when you enable it. First paragraph after the heading: `1. Choose a Starting Point`, [seems to be saying the same thing](http://developers.squarespace.com/initial-setup).

Comment: You are right, [this is what I read](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/206545717#toc-can-i-customize-blocks-and-cover-pages-in-the-developer-platform-) "it doesn’t allow changes to HTML markup of our blocks..." seems it only applies to certain blocks though not the whole markup

Comment: Thank you @hsawires for answering my question. when i put this into the custom css it says 'syntax error on line 1' - i understand this is a html but I'm not sure where to place the code? i.e. how to 'restructure my html body'?

Comment: @LaurenBasser What software are you using for editing html to gives you that error? ... I what I meant of restructuring your html is to add 4 DIVs as a main container instead of the body.

Comment: @hsawires it worked! I realised I was placing the code into css like a noob. I didn't want to enable the developer platform as this (to my understanding) would mean that I would need to code the entire site, however I figured out that i needed to place the code in the code injection under settings > advanced. Thank you so much for all your help!